# Using Javascript to roll back a date in a specific format

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how to do this part, or even how to pose it as a question.  I've been working on a project for my job in which we have a start date and an end date that the user enters either through a datepicker, or typing it in, within certain formatting requirements which then sends a query to our database to request information.   The start and end date are auto-populated when the page loads, with the start date going back 14 days to give the user an auto two weeks information unless they wanted to get more/less.  Here's the problem:

1:  Both input boxes (html of course) were working, up until we hit October because it's a 2 digit month.
2:  The rollback date of -14 gives a negative number instead of rolling back the date to September XX.

I've tried  var StartDay = StartDate.setDate(StartDate.getDate() - 14); and all that gives is the date and time which SQL does not recognize.  So I'm trying to figure out how to either:

1:  Get it to roll back to the correct date which I can then populate the box with, or
2:  Re-format the datetime given to a format that will be yyyy-mm-dd

So far I've spent all day searching for an answer and I've found multiple that are close but not quite all that I'm looking for.

```
          $(function () {
          $("#StartDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", changeMonth: true });
          $("#EndDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", changeMonth: true });

          var StartDate = new Date();
          var StartDay = StartDate.setDate(StartDate.getDate() - 14);

          var StartMonth = StartDate.getMonth() + 1;
          var StartYear = StartDate.getFullYear();

          //if (StartMonth < 10) StartMonth = "0" + Month;
          //if (StartDay < 10) StartDay = "0" + StartDay;
          var StartDateBox = StartDate;


          var EndDate = new Date();
          var EndDay = EndDate.getDate();
          var EndMonth = EndDate.getMonth() + 1;
          var EndYear = EndDate.getFullYear();
          //alert('the new date is ' + EndDay);

          if (EndMonth < 10) EndMonth = "0" + Month;
          if (EndDay < 10) EndDay = "0" + EndDay;

          var EndDateBox = EndYear + "-" + EndMonth + "-" + EndDay;

          $("#StartDate").attr("value", StartDateBox);
          $("#EndDate").attr("value", EndDateBox);
      });
```

Everything labled "End" works fine.  It's the rollback of 14 days that I'm having the issue with.  I have the "if" commented out because the number is a negative and therefore crashes the function.

*edit Awesome!  Much appreciated, now that I see it, it makes more sense.  However, it's set to August, so it's missing the +1 after .getMonth.  I'll try to figure that out.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Your line `StartDate.setDate(StartDate.getDate() - 14);` will subtract 14 from the date correctly. For example, if the date is October 8th, that line will result in a date of September 24th.

Comment: The problem is it will give me the date if I use this version, but that date is in the wrong format and I'm not sure how to format it the way I need it too.  The other way, just gives a negative number and crashes the function.   So the End box gives 2014-10-08 and I need the Start box to do the same formatting for SQL to recognize it.   The StartDate.setDate(StartDate.getDate() - 14); gives me the entire Wed Sep 24 2014 14:30:25 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time).   So I guess after breaking it down to what I need, is to reformat that into the same as the End box.

Comment: The Date object doesn't have a format. That format you see is just a string representation of the Date object. You can format the `StartDate` obejct the same exact way you format the `EndDate` object.

Comment: How so?  I had the start date setup the same way and it gives 2014-10-0-7 because it was a -7 at the time (7th of October -14 days)  it wasn't rolling it back to september.

Comment: I think your main issue is that you are using the result of `setDate` as your day. It looks to me like that doesn't return what you are expecting. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a function for formatting your dates, to reuse that code.

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
    if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
};

$(function () {
    $("#StartDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", changeMonth: true });
    $("#EndDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", changeMonth: true });

    var StartDate = new Date();
    StartDate.setDate(StartDate.getDate() - 14);
    var StartDateBox = formatDate(StartDate);

    var EndDate = new Date();
    var EndDateBox = formatDate(EndDate);

    $("#StartDate").attr("value", StartDateBox);
    $("#EndDate").attr("value", EndDateBox);
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, much appreciated.  Once I've seen it, it makes sense now (isn't that how it always works?)

Comment: Glad I could help. And yes, that happens a lot :)